# Eloquent whereRaw is not working with bindings

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have a `json` column in my database with french characters. So when I use:

```
App\Job::where('name->fr', 'like', '%Fune%')->count();
```

It is not finding results for jobs that has an accent in the name like `Funéraire`. I can accomplish what I want by adding a collate in the query using the `whereRaw`:

```
App\Job::whereRaw('json_unquote(json_extract(`name`, \'$."fr"\')) LIKE \'%Fune%\' collate utf8mb4_general_ci')->count();
```

However, when I use bindings in my `whereRaw` method:

```
App\Job::whereRaw('json_unquote(json_extract(`name`, \'$."fr"\')) LIKE ? collate utf8mb4_general_ci', ['%Fune%'])->count();
```

I am receiving a database error:

> COLLATION 'utf8mb4_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary' (SQL: select count(*) from `jobs` where json_unquote(json_extract(`name`, '$."fr"')) LIKE %Fune% collate utf8mb4_general_ci)

Just wondering why it's not working when I'm passing it with bindings.

Comment: The error is actually more correct. The collation of JSON columns in MySQL is always a binary unicode collation.

Comment: @apokryfos But then why is it working if I use a raw query?

Comment: I'll speculate that: A raw string will match the encoding of the connection, not the column. A prepared string will match the encoding of the column. The `utf8mb4_general_ci` collation might not apply to the column encoding while it applies to the connection encoding

Comment: This works for me: `whereRaw('json_unquote(json_extract(`name`, \'$."fr"\')) LIKE convert(? using utf8mb4)', ['%Fune%'])`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Can you post it as the answer? It's working for me too. I'll accept it :)

Comment: There should be no need to change collation. Could you tell us which `collation` is set for your db driver in `config/database.php`? By default, Laravel uses `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and that matches `e` with `è` or`é`

Comment: @Adam I have the default collation but that doesn't work for json columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the binding to UTF-8:

```php
App\Job::whereRaw(
    'json_unquote(json_extract(name, \'$."fr"\')) LIKE convert(? using utf8mb4)', 
    ['%Fune%']
)
```

Comment: Had to use this: `convert(? using utf8mb4) collate utf8mb4_general_ci`

Answer (score 0):

Chin.

if you have a JSON column the DB, you can directly fire a like query on the column as JSON is a string and like %text% search the text in the string.

you don't have to go through this much trouble for finding the alike name.

your query may somewhat look like this,

```
App\Job::where('name_of_column_of_json', 'like', '%Fune%')->count();
```

and you will get the desired output.

hit it and let us know, It works or not.

Comment: I've already tried that. It was my first attempt, but as I mentioned in my question, it is not working for results that has a french character such as `Funéraire`. It would only work if I query for `%Fun%` instead.

Comment: Have to tries passing 'Funé' as input, I guess this will work.

Comment: That's the point of my question... I want it to find the result even if I search for `Fune`... I know it will work if I search with accents.