# COLLATION 'utf8mb4_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, collation

I want to find a user in my Laravel app with name "Y**ı**lmaz" by searching for "Y**i**lmaz"

by default in Laravel (with `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` as collation for my connection) this

```
\App\User::whereRaw('name LIKE ?', '%Yilmaz%')->get();
```

returns nothing.

As I found out at [MySQL does not treat ı as i?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59211363/mysql-does-not-treat-%c4%b1-as-i/59213587?noredirect=1#comment104643952_59213587), it works with collation `utf8mb4_general_ci`. However, it is not recommended to use `utf8mb4_general_ci` as default collation because it is not accuratly [sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/766996/2311074).

My first try was

```
\App\User::whereRaw('name LIKE ? collate utf8mb4_general_ci', '%Yilmaz%')->get();
```

but this throws

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1253 COLLATION 'utf8mb4_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary' (SQL: select * from `users` where name LIKE %Yilmaz% collate utf8mb4_general_ci)

Next, I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/58493518/2311074

```
\App\User::whereRaw('name LIKE convert(? using utf8mb4)', '%Yilmaz%')->get();
```

but this returns

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'like' (SQL: select * from `users` where name LIKE convert(%Yilmaz% using utf8mb4))

How can I change collation to `utf8mb4_general_ci` in Laravel only for one query?

Comment: Is the column `name` configured to use a binary collation in MySQL? That looks like an overlook if you need to search this way.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález column `name` as collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combination of both works for me:

```
\App\User::whereRaw(
    'name LIKE convert(? using utf8mb4) collate utf8mb4_general_ci',
    '%Yilmaz%'
)->get();
```

But I am not sure if this is the best approach.

Comment: Or...  `'name LIKE _utf8mb4 ? collate utf8mb4_general_ci'`,